# Search functionality in reduxReact-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to achieve search functionality in redux

I am using the following code but its not working but the same code is working in plain javascript but not with redux

```
 searchItems: (name ) => async (dispatch) => {
    let newData = []
    dispatch({
      type: types.SEARCH_ITEMS,
      payload: (newData = DATA.filter((item) => {
        const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;       
        const textData = name.toUpperCase();
        itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;       
        return newData;
      })),
    });
  },
};
```

> the newData is returning and empty array

```
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type } = action;

  switch (type) {    
    case types.SEARCH_ITEMS:
      return [...action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

What am i dong wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return from the filter callback `true` or `false`:

Try to do it this way:

```js
searchItems: (name ) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.SEARCH_ITEMS,
      payload: DATA.filter((item) => {        
        const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;       
        const textData = name.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      }),
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much